# In R, how do i make one variable and column the X axis of a histogram

Tags: r, variables, histogram, axis

There are 7 different tree types and I'd like to find out which tree is most climbed. I would like to plot it in a histogram but I don't know how to make that variable into the x axis.

[This is the data I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34EJo.png)

[This is what I want the end result to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESsgw.png)

Comment: You're a looking at nominal data, those are types of trees, if yout description is correct. There is clearly no tree of type 3.5 or 2.7654 ;-) You want to look at a barplot or its alternatives instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ggplot2` package, that's what you are searching for :

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Tree,y=count)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

With `df` being that dataframe of your screen.

Comment: I am glad that I could help. Also, you should check the R-graph gallery where you could inspire for your future graphs.  

https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/